# java.lang.classnotfoundexception org.springframework.web.servlet.dispatcherservlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to run a sample Spring MVC application with the following resources

**IDE : eclipse(indigo)
Server : Tomcat7
Build Tool : No build tool (Trying to run manually)**

and it is giving me the following exception:

```
**INFO: Marking servlet spring as unavailable
16 May, 2014 12:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /Spring3MVC threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)**
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

I am posting my web.xml and spring configuration file below:

### **Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>ShopManagement</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>             
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### **Spring Configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="shop.mgmt.web" />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <!-- <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/message" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean> -->
</beans>
```

**I have all the jars related to Spring MVC in WEB-INF\lib folder and also in build path.**

please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse IDE right click on project choose **properties**, choose **Deployment Assembly** make sure source and deploy path right, also any libs that you use out side web/inf must be deploy in WEB-INF/lib. After that try clean project and clean tomcat server and publish web application again.
Check this post hope it can help you [eclipse web application and maven dependency issues](http://devjav.com/eclipse-web-application-maven-dependency-issues/)

Comment: Hi Pham,Thanks for your response. I am able to check whether my source path is correct or not But how can I check whether my deployment path is correct or not.

Comment: Hi Pham, I am able to resolve this issue. Actually the problem is with the <url-pattern> in web.xml. The url request that I am passing does not match with any url pattern in web.xml. Thanks for supporting me.